# How can i call the webservice from my emulator which is on my local system?

Tags: android, web-services

"Sorry this is my first time to create/use a web service" 
I have created a "Simple Web Service" on my local system, how can i use/call it on my Android device & Emulator?

**EDIT:**

```
"how to use the web service which is on my local system"?
```

Comment: i don't know it is still applicable, however you can use  http://10.0.2.2 instead of localhost for emulator and  "http://10.0.1.2 in case of accessing service from USB drive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[this link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/webservice-from-android.aspx) will give you step by step information of webservice access from android

in that example at URL variable

```
private static final String URL = 
    "http://192.168.202.124:9000/AndroidWS/wsdl/ServiceImpl.wsdl";
```

use your local ip address

Answer (score 3):

Google it you will get it. have look to this [Calling web service from android app](http://jatin4rise.wordpress.com/2010/10/03/webservicecallfromandroid/)

hope it will help you. All the best.!!

Comment: Thanks. Can i use the webservice which is on my local system?

Comment: yeah see swan given solution for the same.

Comment: @YaqubAhmad hey hi u can use webservice that is on your local system for that make sure that your local server is running and check that whether your webservice is successfully deploy and running...

Comment: OK, i will ensure that its deployed properly.